# How do i mock the JSON response for testing in angular 4 project

Tags: angular, mocking

I want to run my application with all mocks JSONs to start with to avoid dependency of web service. Whats the ideal way to mock the JSON in local so that with minimal change instead of calling the actual service it should get response from local file.I have a folder where i keep all my mock JSON files.

Comment: You can create a http service and provide your absolute path where you have mocks. Once you verify you can update the mock path to the actual apis

Comment: Thats all manual effort right? Any way i can switch ?

Answer (score 0):

I used to mock by keeping a local JSON file like you did. But the problem is you can only use GET method and can't use other HTTP method like post or put. I end up using a website like [https://www.mocky.io](https://www.mocky.io/) and [https://www.owllang.com](https://www.owllang.com/)
to mock my API. That way in my code I only need to change the URL and everything is the same. I can also use any HTTP method I want. Hope this help.

Answer (score -2):

I have used the following approach in my app: create a folder called 'API', with JSON files in it. Each JSON file represents an `http.get` call.

**Example:**

In your API service, create a data member called `mock`:

```js
private mock = false;
```

Let's say you have an API to receive a list of people. Copy the real response to a JSON file (e.g `people.JSON`) and save it in a mock data folder, like `api`.

When you want to run your app without accessing the real API data, set `mock` to `true`;

```js
private mock = true;
```

And the function:

```js
getPeopleList() : Observable<any> {
    var endpoint = this.myEndpoint; // Your real API url

    if(this.mock) {
      endpoint = '/api/people.json';
    }

    return this.http.get(endpoint)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Hope this is what you mean.

Comment: What if its a POST call and i have to switch with a get call.

Comment: May be you can create a simple nodeJS API with mock reponse for GET, POST etc and use that from the Angular project.

sample:
import express from 'express';
import mockJSON from '../mocks/mockJSON.json';

const app = express();


app.get('/url/', (req, res) => {
 res.status(200).json(mockJSON);
});
app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Running on localhost:8080"));

Comment: An API should never know if it is under test or if it's in production. An API should just do what it does. You should set the endpoint accordingly